# index.php не открывается

Tags: php, debian, mod-rewrite

Уже неделю не могу справиться с проблемой на своем сайте (захожу по IP, так как домен еще не привязал). При введении IP в адресную строку происходит httperror500, 
иные файлы или скрипты с сервера (ipadress/script.php) срабатывает
При открытие ipadress/index.php ошибка аналогичная http error 500
OC - debian 8
apache 2.4.10
на win10 через openserver этот же сайт работает на ура, а вот на vps не получается

htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
ErrorDocument 500 /crookedmirror.php
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

apach2.conf изменил только allowoverride на папке с сайтом (htaccess лежит в папке html

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

default-000.conf:

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@admin
        Documentroot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
<VirtualHost>
```

Comment: На OpenServer высокий порог игнорирования ошибок. Попробуйте поискать ошибку в коде index.php

Comment: ну дак логи то посмотрите, чего гадать?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка 500 - это ошибка обработки кода вашего файла. Т.к. другие файлы php у вас работают, следовательно это ошибка конкретно файла index.php

Проверьте логи своего сервера, чтобы понять что именно вызывает сбой.

Если не знаете где их искать, то допишите в htaccess

```
php_flag log_errors on 
php_value error_log /home/u988648785/public_html/error_log.txt
```

Обратите внимание, путь к логу ошибок надо заменить на свой.

Затем запустите index.php ещё раз и посмотрите что у вас поломалось в логах.